# Partial cloning

Tags: apex, related-list, clone

I'd like to write an Apex Class that partially clones Opportunities.
Partially means I want to clone my related custom products, but not my related tenders (we call it "RFQs").

If I got it right, the clone method clones all relations.
Now I tried to clone, reset RFQ relation and saving afterwards, but resetting is not working.

```
Opportunity newOpp = oldOpp.clone(false, true, false, false);
.
.
.
newOpp.RFQs__c = null;
insert newOpp;
```

I tried the above, assigning an empty list, tried with and without "__c" and "__r", using "put()"-Method, nothing works.

I don't fully understand the naming conventions of Salesforce for related lists. UI says on RFQs Opportunity field: "Child Relationship Name = RFQs". So I'd guess, that `newOpp.RFQs__c` should work, but the result is "Variable does not exist".

Any ideas?

### tl;dr

How do I unset a relation on a cloned record with Apex before saving the record?

Comment: The clone method doesn't duplicate child records out of the box. You can't "clear" the child relationship, it's just a way of querying in the other direction when you want to load all children etc. I suspect you have other code that's duplicating the children for the record, or the children for the original are being updated to point to the new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was indeed a mistake in my test class which made me think that all relations are cloned too. Now it's working as expected.